# activity error in manifest file in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, manifest, runtimeexception

I have a manifest error. It was fine at first time.
But i chagned it to "public class color_dia extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener"
and it was red line on color_dia in manifest file.

when i click a button related to color_dia. it makes error
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo"

what should i do?

```
import android.app.Dialog;

import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import static android.graphics.Color.rgb;


    public class color_dia extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public color_dia(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    }

    public color_dia(Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
        mActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Pick Line Color");
        setContentView(R.layout.color_dia);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to launch `color_dia` using `startActivity()`? Please edit your question and post the error message including stacktrace from logcat into your question.

Comment: @DavidWasser I launch color_dia suing startActivityForResult().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot launch a `Dialog` using `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`. You can only launch activities (class that `extends Activity`). A `Dialog` is shown in an `Activity` by calling `showDialog()` (or use `DialogFragment`). Please read about the difference between `Dialog` and `Activity` in the Android documentation or find a suitable tutorial to follow.